# What Control is the Eclipse Workspace Pane Using?

Tags: widget, swt

I'm looking (unsuccessfully) for the controller/widget that gives the Eclipse IDE the ability to rearrange panes within the workspace.  Very powerful!  For instance, you can

- combine panes into tabs and separate them again
- place panes on the top, bottom, left, right or center.
- place panes under, over, within the left, and within the right of current panes
- pull panes into their on top-level window or re-integrate them into the main window
- double click a pane to take over the entire workspace or snap it back to its original position
- minimize a pane to a side bar
- etc!

Any idea how this is done and if I can also use the widget to create a workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single widget, which does it all. There is a myriad of classes, which combined accomplished what is known as the Workbench. That's said, it would be difficult to reuse the functionality without starting up full-blown Workbench.

Here are some hints where to start looking:

- `org.eclipse.ui.internal.LayoutPart` class
- `org.eclipse.ui.presentations.AbstractPresentationFactory` class
- `org.eclipse.ui.presentationFactory` extension point
- [Eclipse Wiki regarding custom RCP look & feel](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_Custom_Look_and_Feel)

The problem is that almost everything has connection back to `Workbench` and `WorkbenchWindow` classes, which make it difficult to use them without bringing the whole RCP.